# Conformation of a simile

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> निगाह-ए-गुल से बुलबुल यूँ गिरी है गिरे जिस तरह तिनका आशियां से

Literal English translation

> The nightingale's fallen from the flower's view as a twig falls from nest

I think it's a simile. Original passage indicates she has fallen from the higher to the lower position in her flower's view.( I mean she has fallen into disgrace) dose the translation conveys the meaning of disgrace or something else? Thank you.

Comment: If it's a simile, then only look at what comes after *as* for the meaning. I see nothing other than a literal statement—certainly nothing to do with disgrace.

Answer (score -1):

There's a metaphor, not a simile.

According to Merriam-Webster's  Dictionary (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/simile#note-1):

***Simile vs. 
Metaphor***

Many people have trouble distinguishing between simile and metaphor. 
A glance at their Latin and Greek roots offers a simple way of telling these two closely-related figures of speech apart. 
Simile comes from the Latin word similis 
(meaning “similar, like”), 
which seems fitting, since the comparison indicated by a similewill typically contain the words as or like. 
Metaphor, on the other hand, comes from the Greek word metapherein 
(“to transfer”), 
which is also fitting,
 since a metaphor is used in place of something.

“My love is like a red, red rose” is a simile,

and “love is a rose” is a metaphor.

Comment: “... as a twig falls from the nest”, so there is a simile, surely?  Though perhaps the whole thing is a metaphor.